# Crystal Reports creates 6 pages from a single record

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have been working with crystal reports for some time but the current problem has left me at a loss.

The report has three page headers (a, b c) and two detail sections (a, b) and it also contains a sub report in detail (a). The report was migrated from vs2008 to vs2010 and it used to work without any problem.

After migration however I have noted that the report generates six (6) pages even when the main report and the sub report returns a single record. However, the logo image which is placed on page header (a) only prints once.

I have tried merging some of the sections and also removing the sub report but problem persists. I have also looked at questions with similar titles but none seems related to my problem. I have verified the page size and confirmed non of the sections exceed the page size.

Suggestions on how to force the report to print correctly would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Post a picture of the report in design mode.

Comment: I have posted the report in design mode as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with the problem for a whole day, I finally found where the problem was.

The report is using a dataset with two tables; one for the company logo and the other for the main data. In VS2008, the two tables were linked but after upgrading to VS2010, the links were broken. Trying to re-establish the links was not possible as the tables were not appearing under the Database Expert... Links tab. Dropping the table with the logo from the report database made the report display correctly. The only question which I was unable to answer was why the report was producing six pages.

I arrived at this conclusion after re-creating the new report afresh with the same tables and the problem recurred.

Comment: Had I seen this earlier, I would have suggest checking your 'Start new page after' options in each of your subsections.